# Recommended datatype fixed length in mysql

Tags: mysql, datatypes

What's the best data type for store fix length data such as

- MD5 password `1f3870be274f6c49b3e31a0c6728957f`
- HEX Ccolor `f2a709`

They don't need character sets. All in absolute `[a-z0-9]{6}` for color, `[a-z0-9]{32}` for `md5`

I use BINARY data type for that. Is this a good choice or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing the literal values in a `BINARY` column is an efficient choice but only of you want comparisons to be case-sensitive such that 'a' != 'A'.

Given the same data (essentially hexadecimal digits only), if you wanted case insensitivity then you would want to use `latin1` where 'a' = 'A'.

Both of these will use 1 byte per character.

However, you can use half a byte per character if you are willing to pack the data on the way in and unpack it on the way out.  For HTML color codes, use a 3 byte column `BINARY (3)`.

```
INSERT INTO html (color) VALUES (UNHEX('f2a709'));

SELECT HEX(color) AS color FROM html;
# would return 'F2A709' 
# use LOWER() around HEX () if you want the lowercase equivalent returned.
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html

Comment: i use `binary` for hex color, is any performance issue between `char(6)` and `binary(6)` ? char need to have process character set layer.

Comment: There's a theoretical performance difference between the two because the `BINARY` data type does not require character set handling, but I would speculate that the difference would be so small that it would be difficult to measure.